# How to convert text to \x codes?

Tags: php, hex, encode

I want to convert normal text to \x codes for e.g \x14\x65\x60

For example :

```
normal text = "base64_decode"
converted \x codes for above text = "\x62\141\x73\145\x36\64\x5f\144\x65\143\x6f\144\x65"
```

How to do this?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP 5.3 one-liner:

```
echo preg_replace_callback("/./", function($matched) {
    return '\x'.dechex(ord($matched[0]));
}, 'base64_decode');
```

Outputs `\x62\x61\x73\x65\x36\x34\x5f\x64\x65\x63\x6f\x64\x65`

Comment: not working for my special string: `base64_decode('OVUP/PZrLzoZpaeQga/TpK9xeJAOuTTbUzm9NplDuhSUMkklPtDeDQDgidUEIX+ijxe80EI')`

Comment: It works just fine on my computer with that string. I could not see why it can't work unless you have PHP version older that 5.3.

Comment: Sorry my fault, it's good, with results slightly different from @DaveRandom's.

Answer (score 5):

The `ord()` function gives you the decimal value for a single byte. `dechex()` converts it to hex. So to do this, loop through the every character in the string and apply both functions.

Answer (score 3):

```
$str = 'base64_decode';
$length = strlen($str);
$result = '';

for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) $result .= '\\x'.str_pad(dechex(ord($str[$i])),2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);

print($result);
```

Comment: `str_pad` is unneeded here: it should only match `\x[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,2}`

Answer (score 1):

Here's working code:

```
function make_hexcodes($text) {
    $retval = '';
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($text); ++$i) {
        $retval .= '\x'.dechex(ord($text[$i]));
    }

    return $retval;
}

echo make_hexcodes('base64_decode');
```

**[See it in action](http://www.ideone.com/VLVKV)**.

Comment: @DaveRandom: Why pad? Also, the [string parsing rules](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) don't require escaping in this particular case. You can see for yourself by clicking on the live example link or reading the docs.

Comment: because any character with a value of less than 16 will result in, e.g. `\xa` rather than `\x0a`. Thinking about it, I don't know if this matters, I have always just assumed it does. And escape your backslash because it needs escaping. In a single quoted string it does matter so much, but it's still good practice.

Comment: @DaveRandom: Sorry, I have to disagree. The documentation is pretty clear that padding is not required and that the slash in `'\x'` does not need escaping.

Comment: The page you linked do says explicitly, in the 'Single Quoted' section: `To specify a literal backslash, double it (\\)`. PHP is pretty good at working out what you meant, but since you can still use \ to specify a literal single quote, you technically should escape the backslash.

Comment: @DaveRandom: And it continues: *All other instances of backslash will be treated as a literal backslash: this means that the other escape sequences you might be used to, such as \r or \n, will be output literally as specified rather than having any special meaning*. I don't think it's a matter of "working out what you want": those are *documented rules*.

Comment: Granted, and I do accept your point and that it will work without it. I think the manual should be clearer really, since the only time it would matter is if you wanted a literal `\'` in a single quoted string.

Answer (score 1):

For an alternative to `dechex(ord())` you can also use [`bin2hex($char)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php), [`sprintf('\x%02X')`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) or [`unpack('H*', $char)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php). Additionally instead of using `preg_replace_callback`, you can use `array_map` with `str_split`.

### Hexadecimal Encoding: https://3v4l.org/Ai3HZ

**bin2hex**

```php
$word = 'base64_decode';
echo implode(array_map(function($char) {
    return '\x' . bin2hex($char);
}, (array) str_split($word)));
```

**unpack**

```php
$word = 'base64_decode';
echo implode(array_map(function($char) {
    return '\x' . implode(unpack('H*', $char));
}, (array) str_split($word)));
```

**sprintf**

```php
$word = 'base64_decode';
echo implode(array_map(function($char) {
    return sprintf('\x%02X', ord($char));
}, (array) str_split($word)));
```

**Result**

```
\x62\x61\x73\x65\x36\x34\x5f\x64\x65\x63\x6f\x64\x65
```

---

### Hexadecimal Decoding

To decode the encoded string back to the plain-text, use one of the following methods.

```php
$encoded = '\x62\x61\x73\x65\x36\x34\x5f\x64\x65\x63\x6f\x64\x65';
$hexadecimal = str_replace('\x', '', $encoded);
```

**hex2bin**

```
echo hex2bin($hexadecimal);
```

**pack**

```
echo pack('H*', $hexadecimal);
```

**sscanf + vprintf**

```php
vprintf(str_repeat('%c', count($f = sscanf($hexadecimal, str_repeat('%02X', substr_count($encoded , '\x'))))), $f);
```

**Result**

```
base64_decode
```

Answer (score 0):

im not read this code **\ud83d\udc33**

```
function unicode_decode(string $str)
    {
       str="Learn Docker in 12 Minutes \ud83d\udc33"
        return preg_replace_callback('/u([0-9a-f]{4})/i', function ($match) {
            return mb_convert_encoding(pack('H*', $match[1]), 'UTF-8', 'UCS-2BE');
        }, $str);
    }
```