# Ideas what this output means?

Tags: php, encoding, character

Could anyone tell what does this mean? What kind of coding is this? My error log in PHP gives the following kind of code:

```
\xc3\xb6m\xc3\xb6\xc3\xa4
```

What kind of list should I be searching for to interpet this output?

thanx for any replies :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320516/how-to-convert-text-to-x-codes

Comment: [Unicode Converter Page](http://rishida.net/tools/conversion/)  This should help you with Unicode.